# Does SVG automatically resize for retina displays?

Tags: browser, html, css, svg

I'm trying to make my webpage look great on every device, I have an Retina Macbook 15" and an iPhone 5, and a regular low DPI desktop, so I want it to look as good as possible on all of them, and I can't seem to find a site online that talks about Retina SVGs, they'll talk your ear off about "image fonts" and PNGs though. lol

and, how do I make sure the SVGs are rendered properly across browsers?

Comment: SVG files will just be resized accordingly, so I don't see an issue (except for older browsers). But the real solution to deal with this would be to provide actual retina graphics (see http://retinajs.com/ for example).

Comment: "Retina" is just Apple's marketing for the current generation of displays (which feature higher definition than the previous generation), so your question is rather how to provide hints at the scale at which the vector graphics should be rendered.

Comment: I know what retina means, I'm asking if an SVG file will take up the same physical space regardless of res, and how to make it do that if it won't automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "preserveAspectRatio" and "viewBox" attributes of the  tag - that should take care of all the SVG rendering you need in a Web page.